# Why this question marked as duplicate?

Tags: discussion, support

I posted this [question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/88200/how-to-increase-the-speed-of-exposed-autocomplete-field-in-views-using-drupal-6), but it is marked as duplicate for already have an answer. But my question is related to drupal 6 and the referenced post is for Drupal 7 and the referenced question is not exactly similar. My question is related to Views exposed filter and not the performance of entire drupal 6.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first - please be civil. There's no need to call someone 'blind' for voting to close a question - please give the benefit of the doubt that they did so in good faith.

On to the issue. The question has a single close vote (as you can see in the screenshot you posted), it's not actually closed. I can't see anything in the edit history to suggest it has ever been closed.

To address the new question you're now asking

> Why this question marked as duplicate?

Questioning individuals' motivations for voting to close a single question, one time, isn't really a constructive area of discussion. I would say you can boil it down to one of these reasons:

- The voter made a mistake (it happens) or
- The voter genuinely thought that your question would be answered by the proposed duplicate

Either way, your knowing the 'real' motivation (if there is such a thing in this case) doesn't help anybody. It was voted for closure as a duplicate, so (in my opinion anyway) the answer to your question is that it was marked as a duplicate because the person doing the marking thought it was a duplicate.

Unless 4 other people agree with that assertion, you have nothing to worry about.

Comment: @Molot, it's my mistake and on what criteria this question marked as duplicate.

Comment: @Molot, I updated the question

Comment: @Bala and now I was able to post an answer.

Answer (score 2):

To add what Clive said, the question has been voted to be closed from a single user; what you see as the user who asked the question is that "This question may have already have an answer here" header showing you the question your question is duplicating, which (basing on that screenshot) is a question that is already closed. Don't get confused from the *[closed]* part you see, as that is referring to the question the users think it's the duplicated question.

In fact, what I see as a user who didn't asked that question is the following. (I took the screenshot now, after the closing votes were increased by one.)

> [image: screenshot]

The supposed duplicate is https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/724/why-is-drupal-7-so-slow which was closed as not constructive.

Comment: thanks Kiamlaluno for better understanding on how it works for other users.

Answer (score 1):

Word "exact" was removed from duplicate vote for a reason.

If questions are different, but asks about the same thing and **differ only in aspects irrelevant to actual problem** and problem's solutions, they can be closed as duplicates - or that's what I remember. I do genuinely believe that both the problem and solutions are basically the same. I believe that most voted answer, that boils down to "debug for bottlenecks and come back when you know them" is right for you and for most similar questions. And I think marking a duplicate was most constructive way to deal with your question, as without knowing what exactly slows you, answering your question is plainly impossible.

Now, it's a vote for a reason. I may be right, I may be wrong, it will take any effect beyond a comment only if 4 more people thinks I'm right. Until then, and week after, you can edit your question to highlight actual differences, for example to post any problems that happens only when filters are accessed and cause slowness, or benchmark of various uncached data accessed, to show problem really is isolated to this part of your site (and not merely most visible there).

Comment: Once again sorry for that. best thing is I want to delete that comment with your acceptance and so you may delete that too.

Comment: @Bala No problem, I'm not angry or anything. Hope that now my reasoning is clear, and feel free to disagree with it. By the way, I just updated my answer.